# Assigns a function to PreviewTextInput in the Texbox preserving the WPF pattern

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a window named MechanicView.xaml and its back-end that is MechanicView.xaml.cs. The MechanicView.xaml window is connected via DataContext to the MechanicViewModel.cs file. The MechanicView.xaml window contains a TextBox with a PreviewTextInput event. How do I assign a function to the PreviewTextInput event that will be in the MechanicViewModel.cs file? I want to keep the MVVM pattern so I want to avoid creating a function in the MechanicView.xaml.cs file

My actually code in MechanicView.xaml

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding StartNumber, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" PreviewTextInput="TextBox_PreviewTextInput" FontSize="16" Height="27" Margin="10" >
```

My actually code in MechanicView.xaml.cs

```
private void TextBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e) 
{
   Regex regex = new Regex("[^0-9]+"); 
   e.Handled = regex.IsMatch(e.Text); 
}
```

Comment: Call `var viewModel = (MechanicViewModel)DataContext;` in .xaml.cs, then use whatever method you want from `viewModel`! This does not violate MVVM

Comment: Another option is to use `XamlBehaviorsWpf` from microsoft, see [this example](https://github.com/Microsoft/XamlBehaviorsWpf/wiki/InvokeCommandAction), and [this one](https://github.com/Microsoft/XamlBehaviorsWpf/wiki/CallMethodAction).

Comment: First of all, the xaml.cs file is just a file. It has nothing to do with MVVM or *any* design pattern that has ever existed or will exist. MVVM is *only* concerned with application structure/architecture. This means handling events in the .xaml.cs file is perfect. MVVM *only* cares about strict separation of UI and data.

Comment: Secondly, you are about to  violate MVVM - only because you irrationally believe that handling UI events (UI logic) in the view model is more acceptable than having code-behind.TextInput is a routed event, a UI event, that reacts to user input. And users and UI don't exist for the view model. You can bind the TextBox.Text property to your view model. This is the only thing that the view model must be interested in: the data of the TextBox.

Comment: You can see this craziness all day long on SO: people move all the UI logic to their view model only to avoid code-behind. That's crazy. To everybody who understands the goal of MVVM it should be clear that UI logic in the view model is absolutely wrong. MVVM is a design pattern with the only purpose to avoid just this... There couldn't be any bigger violation. Where did you learn that code-behind violates MVVM and implementing UI logic in the view model is textbook MVVM? Did you learn that from stackoverflow?

Comment: What ever you want to do when the PreviewTextInput event is raised, do it in the view. And not in the view model. Logically, the .xaml cs belongs to the view. And that's what matters.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I watched the course "TCH_Building an Enterprise App with WPF, MVVM, and Entity Framework Code First". In this course, all the logic was moved to ViewModel. In the files with xaml.cs extensions there was only a constructor with InitializeComponent() function. In all the courses I looked at events of e.g. buttons are moved to viewmodel, I don't understand why in case of textbox and PreviewTextInput event the logic should be in xaml.cs file? When to apply to move the logic to viewmodel and when to leave the code in xaml.cs. What should the correct code look like?

Comment: You **never** move that kind of code to the view model because the view model does not participate in UI logic. By definition, it's not allowed to. The view model can't handle events without registering a callback with the event source. The event is a routed event which is a UI event. The event data and the sender all are references to UI elements. The complete context is UI related. There are a lot of hints that this event is UI related. You either misunderstood the tutorial e.g. your interpretation is wrong or the tutorial is wrong (what is not very unlikely too).

Comment: Simply bind the Text property to your view model. When the property changes then the data is ready. What else could your view model be interested in if not the text value of the input field? It's really simple: UI logic, UI layout and user interaction all belong to the view. The view model only presents data to the view. You want to separate the view from the view model - that's what MVVM is about - isolate the application from the UI.

Comment: It's not about events, commands, XAML, C#, C++, code-behind, classes etc. It's an architectural design pattern that only cares about how you structure the application. And MVVM clearly requires to separate the view from the view model. In other words, you are not allowed to mix responsibilities. The view model never uses the view. That's mandatory. use the Text property and bind it to the view model. Or if you need to handle UI logic implement it in code-behind aka C# - in the view.

Comment: What is your goal? Do you want to validate the text input? Do you want a numeric text box? I can give three clean MMVM options: the first and best option is to extend `TextBox` and create a new control `NumerictextBox` (recommended). Here you can override the `PreviewTextChanged` event or register a Text property changed callback.

Comment: The second option is to bind the `TextBox.Text` property to an `int` property of the view model. The binding engine will try to convert the string in put to the type of the source property. If this conversion fails e.g. because "12ab" is not convertible to `int` then the input is rejected and a red error border is drawn around the TextBox.

Comment: The third option is to implement data validation in your view model by implementing `INotifyDataErrorInfo` and then bind the `TextBox.Text` property to it. You can configure the binding to update on property changed. this would allow you to validate character by character (if that makes sense). Creating a `NumericTextBox` is the cleanest solution as the logic is exactly where it belongs and the feature is very much reusable.

Comment: Instead of using regular expression to check if the string is numeric, better use the static `int.TryParse` method. It will return `false` if the input string is not numeric. It performs better than Regex (at least pre-compile the Regex and store it in an instance or class variable).

Comment: To test a single input character simply use the static `char.IsNumber` method which will also return `false` if the character is not numeric. Don't use Regex here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are number of ways you can accomblish, this is one approach

1. Download [Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf/) nuget package to your project.
2. Add `xmlns:behaviours="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"`  namespace to MechanicView.xaml.
3. Add this code in MechanicView.xaml (not tested)

```
<TextBox Width="150">
   <behaviours:Interaction.Triggers>
       <behaviours:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewTextInput">
           <behaviours:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding PreviewTextInputCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
       </behaviours:EventTrigger>
    </behaviours:Interaction.Triggers>
</TextBox>
```

4. In MechanicViewModel.cs file, add `ICommand PreviewTextInputCommand` variable
5. Implement `PreviewTextInputCommand` variable as below

```
    PreviewTextInputCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(PreviewTextInput, (o) => { return true; });
```

6. The command method will look as below

```
    private void PreviewTextInput(object parameter)
    {
        var p = (parameter?.GetType().Name);
    }
```

Comment: You even pass the original event data to the view model so that it has access to the UI elements. That's quite broken MVVM. Another accepted SO answer that promotes wrong MVVM.